# Simple bash Linux script to run stored procedure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need a bash/Linux shell script which will run my stored procedure only on Wednesday.

I am new to Bash shell scripting.

Below is what I came up with:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

MYSQL="/usr/bin/mysql --compress -hlocalhost -utest -ptest test";

dayofweek=`date +%a`

#if [ ${dayofweek} ='Wed' ] ; then ${MYSQL} -e "CALL testSummary();"; fi ;
```

When I run it:

sh test.sh, it says:

: command not found

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about run `CALL testSummary()` from mysql prompt?
besides `[ ${dayofweek} ='Wed' ]` should be `[ ${dayofweek} = 'Wed' ]`,  no other issue with your script

I created a simple testSummary procedure, it only print value of `select 1 + 1`, running your script gives me the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd be getting the command not found error.
Couldn't the `-e "CALL testSummary();"` part be what's giving it?

Anyway:
You don't need

```
#!/bin/bash
```

If you're running it with

```
$ sh test.sh
```

Now if you made that script executable with

$ chmod +x test.sh

then doing `$ ./test.sh` would be tantamount to calling `/bin/bash test.sh`.

Make up your mind as to whether you want to use bash or sh. They are different.

If you want to run something periodically on Linux, you might want to take a look at this:
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto